# iOS App does not display time elapsed / total duration on certain audio items.

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, avaudiosession

My iOS app streams audio files, plays them via **AVAudioSession**.

For some reason on certain audio items the time elapsed time/total duration does not display on the lock screen.

I tracked the file type to be **.mp3** but it seems that not all **.mp3** files share this issue.

Is there anything I can do on my end to ensure the total duration/time elapsed is displayed on the lock screen?

Comment: Maybe those ones are VBR?

Comment: hmm @Octopus can you explain how an .mp3 encoded in VBR would affect the time/duration indicators on the lock screen?

Answer (score 2):

If the mp3 is recorded in VBR (variable bit rate) there is no direct number-of-bytes to duration-in-seconds conversion. When you know the bitrate, you can directly calculate the remaining time from your current offset in the file, but a VBR file is constantly throttling the bitrate up and down. There should be info about the total duration of the track in the header and using a timer would help predict where you are, but I don't know how your audio player works on your lock screen. It might only know the current offset into the file, from where it can't calculate durations.

It might not be the reason specifically, as I don't know enough about software you are using, but its one possibility. If that's the reason, you could convert the file to a fixed bitrate.

Comment: thanks for this.  a bit offtopic from the question, but how can i determine if an MP3 is encoded in VBR?

Comment: @User3294729579346597634, look for info about bitrate with an audio player or even some file viewers will do this.

Comment: so i double checked and it looks like the mp3 in question has a constant bitrate, i've downloaded a VBR encoded mp3 and attempted to replicate the bug i'm having with no luck - it showed the progress indicators successfully

Comment: i wonder if you can provide a download or a link for one of these mp3 files?